# Flex: css question

Tags: css, apache-flex, flex4

I have class `com.company.project.views.SomeClass`. I have

```
<mx:Form id="form">
    <mx:FormItem>
        <s:Label/>
    </mx:FormItem>
    <mx:FormItem>
        <s:Label/>
    </mx:FormItem>
    <mx:FormItem>
        <s:Label/>
    </mx:FormItem>
</mx:Form>
```

in it. How can I set color to every `Label` in my form (the same color for all) via CSS? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
mx|FormItem s|Label
{
    color:red;
}
```

Or even to narrow:

```
mx|Form#form mx|FormItem s|Label
{
    color:red;
}
```

You can read more about available selector [here](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/CSS+Advanced+Selectors).